# How to get satellite image of a location with latitude and longitude in Python

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, satellite

For my GeoSpatial project, I want to obtain a satellite image of an area.I have the latitude and longitude of that area,I want to get the satellite image (preferably in jpg or png format) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sat-search](https://github.com/sat-utils/sat-search) library to find satellite images using lat/long coordinates. It'll give you the S3 link to download the image and you can download it using [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) or [awscli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli). (e.g. `aws s3 cp s3://remote_url local_image.tif`) After that, you can use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to open the image and crop the area you want, if the original image is too big for your use case. The typical image format for geospatial imagery is GeoTiff (*.tif), which is similar to jpg or png with geocoordinate information. Good luck!